# $scope variable being undefined despite being set inside a $watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularfire, watch

I'm trying to insert some things into my Firebase database using a user's `uid` but it comes out undefined for some reason. Take a look at the code below:

The main controller that sets the user's data information (`authData`) when the page loads:

```
flickrApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', 'Auth', 'shared', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, Auth, shared) {

    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
        shared.setAuth(authData);
        $scope.authData = shared.getAuth();
    });
}]);
```

The service which handles the authentication state and shares it across my controllers:

```
flickrApp.service('shared', function() {

    var authentication = false;

    return {
        getAuth: function () {
            return authentication;
        },
        setAuth: function (auth) {
            authentication = auth;
        }
    };
});
```

Here is where it doesn't work, in my tags controller. The `$scope.authData` is being set correctly in the `$watch` function but when I try to use it in the `var ref` line it says that `$scope.authData` is undefined (so therefore I can't access the `uid`). I can't figure out why this isn't working as it should be..

Do I have to use `$apply` with the watcher function as well or what is wrong?

```
flickrApp.controller('tagsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', 'shared', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, shared) {

    $scope.tagsList = [];
    $scope.shared = shared;

    $scope.$watch('shared.getAuth()', function(authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
        console.log($scope.authData);
    });

    var ref = new Firebase ('https://flickr.firebaseio.com/users/' + $scope.authData.uid);
    var sync = $firebase(ref);

    $scope.addTag = function(tag) {

        $scope.tagsList.push(tag);

        sync.$set({favoriteTags: $scope.tagsList});
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, assignment to ref is being done before the data of $scope.authData is set in $watch. Try to change your code to this:

```
flickrApp.controller('tagsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', 'shared', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebase, shared) {

    $scope.tagsList = [];
    $scope.shared = shared;
    var ref,sync;

    $scope.$watch('shared.getAuth()', function(authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
        console.log($scope.authData);
        if($scope.authData){
            ref = new Firebase ('https://flickr.firebaseio.com/users/' + $scope.authData.uid);
            sync = $firebase(ref);
        }
    });



    $scope.addTag = function(tag) {

        $scope.tagsList.push(tag);

        sync.$set({favoriteTags: $scope.tagsList});
    }
}]);
```

Comment: True, but I thought that wouldn't matter since I run the $watch before setting the ref. But then again, when the $watch is first being run the authencation is false so I guess that explains it. It works now anyway. Cheers :)

Comment: If for first time authData is false, then you should execute the assignment to ref inside if condition. I have updated the answer to do that.